# DNS queries not forwarding

Tags: networking

My net consists of 3 routers: Inet --- router1 ))) router2 --- router3 ))) host1

Host 1 does not get a DNS response. Router 3 is a Netgear appliance so I can't do a NS check from that box. It is configured manually. Router 2 is a system that does get DNS replies and from what I can tell from tcpdump, receives the request from router 3, but doesn't appear to forward the request. Host 1 CAN ping internet.

I'm thinking the problem is in router 2, but why would it forward all packets except DNS queries?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the firewall was blocking it.